# How do I run Borderlands in windowed mode?

Tags: borderlands

Is there any way to run Borderlands in a window, or even better in a border-less full-screen one?

I can only see options for changing the full-screen resolution in the options menu, so I'm hoping I just missed something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing. Turns out, it's really easy. You just need to add `-windowed` to your launch options.

In Steam:

1. Right-click the Borderlands entry in your library.
2. Click Properties.
3. Click Set Launch Options...
4. Enter `-windowed` in the box.

Alternatively, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> while in the game to switch between full-screen and windowed mode.

Comment: What about borderless?

Comment: @Ampersand To run any windowed game borderless (which I've tested with Borderlands) see *(my answer to)* [this question](http://arqade.com/q/17306/56).